# Sort values from a text file highest to lowest python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, text-files

I have a text file which is laid out like this

```
John, 3,4,5
Barry, 8,5,3
Steve,7,3,2
```

I want to be able to sort this by reading from a text file in python by highest to lowest for each person then put them in order so that the output would be something like this.

```
Barry 8
Steve 7
John 5
```

I also want to sort it based on average so that it will calculate the average from the three scores put it in order then print out the answer like so.

```
Barry 5.3333
John 4
Steve 4
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Well all of it really I'm not sure how to find the highest number and then print that.

I know how to work out the average of three number but now when its from a text file if that makes sense?

so im not entirely sure how to go about it at all.

i know how to read and write from a text file and how to sort alphabetically but thats the extend of my knowledge with text files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
from __future__ import division
from operator import attrgetter


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        self.name = name
        self.scores = scores
        self.highscore = max(scores)
        self.avgscore = sum(scores) / len(scores)

with open('scorez.txt') as f:
    players = []
    for line in f:
        elems = line.split(',')
        players.append(Player(elems[0], map(int, elems[1:])))

    byhighscore = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('highscore'), reverse=True)
    byavg = sorted(players, key=attrgetter('avgscore'), reverse=True)

    print('')
    for p in byhighscore:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.highscore))

    print('')
    for p in byavg:
        print('{0} {1:g}'.format(p.name, p.avgscore))
```

Read the file into a list of players and pre-compute the max score and average (this could be deferred if the list of players and or scores were large). Then just sort on the required attribute and print.

The `attrgetter` function might seem a bit strange to a beginner, but it basically just returns the given attribute for each element in the list being sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, or at least provides food for thought.  I am starting from your statement, "I know how to read and write from a text file".

Make a dict from the data in the text file:

```
d = {'John': [3, 4, 5], 'Barry': [8, 5, 3], 'Steve': [7, 3, 2]}
```

Make an averaging function:

```
def avg(s):
    return float(sum(s)) / len(s) if len(s) > 0 else float('nan')
```

Make some new dicts to keep the average and maximum scores:

```
g = {key: max(d[key]) for key in d}
h = {key: avg(d[key]) for key in d}
```

Then this code will print the results you want:

```
for key in sorted(g, key=g.get, reverse=True):
    print(key, g[key])

for key in sorted(h, key=h.get, reverse=True):
    print(key, h[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Pandas is a good direction:

```
import pandas as pd

txt = '''John, 3,4,5 
       Barry, 8,5,3 
       Steve,7,3,2'''

with open('txt_file', 'w') as f:
f .write(txt)

df = pd.read_csv('txt_file',header=None)

df['average'] = df.mean(axis=1)

df.sort_values('average',inplace=True)

print df
```

output:

0   1   2   3   average

0   John    3   4   5   4.000000

2   Steve   7   3   2   4.000000

1   Barry   8   5   3   5.333333